# PHP - Crop an image, and center the resulting image onto a background, using GD

Tags: php, image, gd, image-manipulation, crop

I'm trying to make a simple app which gives a user a standard background/template image onto which they can place their logo/brand/whatever. I've had a look at a few jQuery plugins which allows the user to upload and crop an image, and most of them seem to work by posting the x and y coords, and the width and height, to the server.

I'm able to then use imagecopyresampled() to merge the image with the background image, but (a) the user's image seems to end up really skewed, even when I hard-code dimensions that I know should work, and (b) I need to position the uploaded image pretty much dead-center -- what's the best way to achieve this?

Any help? This is my first time using GD. I'll add my own code if required, but I'm messing with the different GD functions, so I've butchered the one I had before. Will reproduce it.

Thanks